# Using alias to mock static method cause Call to a member function __call() on null on others

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm writting a test case which need to mock a static method:

```
public function test_process_verify_card_succeed()
    {
        // Mock MqttClient
        $this->mock('alias:' . MqttClient::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('publishVerifiedCardMessage')->once()
                ->with('project/controller_01/command', [2, 3], 10)
                ->andReturn('Some json encoded data');
        });
        // ...some logics and assertions
    }
```

This test run & assert as expected. Even when I run all tests on this class, it still successes:
[image]

But when I run test all my tests, some tests failed (even they passed before) and all of failed tests are api tests which return success code

[image]

And all errors return are:

```
 PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  Call to a member function __call() on null

  at vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:98
     94▕ unset($options);
     95▕ 
     96▕ require PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL;
     97▕ 
  ➜  98▕ PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main();
     99▕
```

If I remove `alias:` before my test above, these test failed but all other tests pass.

Note that before these test with static method above was written, all tests pass

I think each test run individually and I dont' understand why this happend.

Comment: Is that Mqtt class a vendor class? If not you should be using a Facade to be able to mock a static method. I think there is a code smell, you are doing something wrong so you end up on this step, specially using Laravel

Comment: Can you include the code that you are trying to mock?